# Access a subnet through another network

Tags: ethernet, nat, subnet

We have some devices connected together through a switch. We need to access them through another network, but because of limitations in available IP addresses, we can't get an IP address from that network.

Q: How to access my devices through an external network? What kind of device should be used?

[image]

**Edit:**
As routers are suggested, I have made some search and found that there is two scenario: sending from local to remote, sending from remote to local, the later is more difficult to me because the remote have only router ip as its dest address, and to send to the right local computer, the only choice is Port Forwarding?

Comment: You'll need a router between your switch and the 'other network'.

Comment: Routers route packets between networks.

Comment: I've edited my question, Is there any choice other than port forwarding when remote computer initiate a connection?

Comment: Port forwarding is only for NAT (the NAPT version). Routing doesn't require port forwarding. You forward ports for NAPT, and you only use that if you must.

Comment: Seriously, doesn't your business have someone who understands networks, or have a vendor to call who understands this? You could be setting your business up to be completely hacked if you don't understand networking.

Comment: @RonMaupin, I am that someone improving myself knowledge :)

Comment: Then you are trying to run before you can walk. There is a huge amount of stuff to learn before you get to routing, and then routing will make sense. After you learn routing, then you can get into hacks like NAPT.

Comment: "but because of IP counts limitation we cant get IP from that network" - without using an already present router or adding at least one IP address for a router (even a NAT router) there's no way you can communicate with that network.

Comment: I few questions in order to help you: 1. when you say another network Im assuming , you are talking something outside your premises so probably something coming up from the internet is this right?. Because what you call other network in your Diagram could be simply another network ( private ) in your company. Please clarify that. 2.What Router do you facing the internet? ( Brand and Model), this is in order you guide you with either your portforwarding , firewall rules etc. 3. I'm assuming you wont have a static PUBLIC ip address for your business right , if you do please reply in order to giv

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may work with router, but security threat always be there. So, firewall is the best option logically as well as security purposes.

Comment: How can I connect directly to one of my device through a router? I know the router itself has an IP address and the address of my device totally different. Sending packet from local net to outside is easy, router save the packet owner address in its table , but the opposite?

Comment: @SAMPro, routers will have an IP address on each router interface, and routers route packets between networks, so each router address will be in a different network. A router doesn't care in which direction the traffic is traveling, only that it knows how to reach the destination network.

Comment: @RonMaupin, what is challenge for me is connecting the remote computer to a local computer. Please see my edits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firewall or if your current switch has is NAT feature 
For local to remote traffic :use source NAT It will NAT with PAT, all your internal system IP into ONE EXTERNAL ip.
Remote to local traffic: Destination NAT one to one, it will nat any external traffic to your local system IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a router or a firewall. You have two scenarios:

**Access from local to remote:**
This will be simple. Just use the router or firewall's LAN IP as the default gateway of your devices. notice that the LAN IP of router and your devices must be in one subnet.

**Access from remote to local:**
You have one single public IP. After setting the default gateway you can configure port forwarding. for example if you want to access windows remote desktop, you must forward external port number 3389 of the public IP to the port number 3389 of your windows machine's local IP address. Thus, You can use just one public IP to access many services in multiple devices.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way here would be either a GRE or a VPN tunnel between the two sites, both of which do require a router on the remote location (and of course on the local). But you need to have a router already there, assuming those devices have access. The original question / diagram unfortunately does not provide enough info to suggest a proper solution (for instance: do these devices have access to internet now? Is that (?) part of the diagram actually internet or part of some partner's network? Are there private or public IP addresses on the remote devices? Is the switch maybe a layer 3 device and supports some limited routing functions?) As it stands now, those devices cannot access internet unless there is a router somewhere, or that switch provides routing and NAT functions to the local network.